# Python - Printing file on Windows w/ Printer Name

Tags: python, printing, ctypes

I am making a program which has a functionality to print things. I have managed to put together this snippet which fetches the name of the default printer (if there is one):

```py
import ctypes

buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
ctypes.WinDLL("winspool.drv").GetDefaultPrinterW(buffer, ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_ulong(1024)))

printerName = buffer.value
```

However I cannot figure out how to actually print the file with this. Using notepad.exe with the -P argument (or running a text file with the print verb) it can print but it opens a notepad window and such, which I want to be silent.

The `print` command does not allow direct printer names, it requires you to set an LPT port and use that.

If you have any clue how to print the file, now that I have the printer name (It's a txt file if that matters) I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Any reason for using *CTypes* and not [\[GitHub\]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)? Also check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).

Comment: Hi! Yes, I actually got this working with pywin32... I'm trying to keep this program to the base library, though.

Comment: So, if you got it working what's the question's purpose?

Comment: I'd like to use only the base library if possible.

Comment: Ok then, but you only need to replace the calls from one module with the other. Is there a particular reason why only the standard library is required? Can you share the current code (that works)?